# Páginação por Id

Tags: php, paginação

```
<?php
include("conectar.php");
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];

if ($id == "") 
{
    $id = 1;
}



$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_trabalhador where codigo =".$id." limit 1");

include("paginacao.php"); // Chama o arquivo que monta a paginação. ex: << anterior 1 2 3 4 5 próximo >>

echo "<br><br>"; // Vai servir só para dar uma linha de espaço entre a paginação e o  conteúdo

while ($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
echo "<table>"; 
    echo  "<tr><td>Nome:</td>";
    echo "<td>".$exibe["Nome"]."</td></tr>";

    echo  "<tr><td>Morada:</td>"; echo "<td>";
    if ($exibe['Morada']){ echo $exibe['Morada'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

    echo "<tr><td>Tipo:</td>";echo"<td>";
    if($exibe['Tipo']){ echo $exibe['Tipo'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

    echo "<tr><td>Email:</td>"; echo "<td>";
    if($exibe['Email']){ echo $exibe['Email'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

    echo "<tr><td>Alvara Numero:</td>";echo"<td>";
    if($exibe['AlvaraNumero']){ echo $exibe['AlvaraNumero'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "   </td></tr>";

   echo "</table>";
   }
   ?>
```

O unico problema neste codigo é Undefined index: id.

paginacao.php

```
// Verifica se esta na primeira página, se nao estiver ele libera o link para anterior
if ( $pg > 0) { 
    echo "<a href=".$PHP_SELF."?pg=".($pg-1) ."class=pg><b>&laquo; anterior</b></a>";
} else { 
    echo "<font color=#CCCCCC>&laquo; anterior</font>";
}

// Faz aparecer os numeros das página entre o ANTERIOR e PROXIMO
for($i_pg=1;$i_pg<$quant_pg;$i_pg++) { 
    // Verifica se a página que o navegante esta e retira o link do número para identificar visualmente
    if ($pg == ($i_pg-1)) { 
        echo "&nbsp;<span class=pgoff>[$i_pg]</span>&nbsp;";
    } else {
        $i_pg2 = $i_pg-1;
        echo "&nbsp;<a href=".$PHP_SELF."?pg=$i_pg2 class=pg><b>$i_pg</b></a>&nbsp;";
    }
}

// Verifica se esta na ultima página, se nao estiver ele libera o link para próxima
if (($pg+2) < $quant_pg) { 
    echo "<a href=".$PHP_SELF."?pg=".($pg+1)." class=pg><b>próximo &raquo;</b></a>";
} else { 
    echo "<font color=#CCCCCC>próximo &raquo;</font>";
}
   ?>
```

Neste ultimo codigo estou com dificuldade em relacionar o primeiro com o segundo.
E por isso deixei um antigo codigo.

EDIT: No primeiro codigo será para mostrar os dados e no segunda efectuara a paginação

Comment: Tens uma vulnerabilidade de injeção de SQL na primeira query do teu primeiro ficheiro e várias potenciais vulnerabilidades de injeção de XSS.

Comment: Não seria `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_trabalhador where codigo =".$id." limit 1");` ? porém tome cuidado com este tipo de solução ela é totalmente vulnerável

Comment: @PauloRoberto Em PHP, `"foo$bar"` é equivalente a `"foo" . $bar`.  (por oposição a strings com plicas, `'foo$bar'`, em que esta substituição não ocorre) http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Correcto. Mas isto serve só para uso pessoal no meu computador. Para eu controlar certos dados.

Comment: @luiscubal estranho.. e quando você quiser colocar uma string que tenha a palavra $id dentro dela sem querer o valor da variavel?

Comment: @PauloRoberto Use plicas. `'foo$id'` não é convertido.

Answer (score 2):

Alterando a resposta já que a pergunta foi reformulada. Primeiramente essa variavel ID não existe. Seria uma variavel para o controle da paginação. Vamos chamar de PAGE e ela é passada via GET.

```
// Inclui a conexão
include("conectar.php");

// maxímo de itens por página
$max = 10;   

// Recebe a página 1 por default
// caso receba via GET o parâmetro page, captura ele 
// usando intval() para garantir que vai receber um valor inteiro
$page = 1;   
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{ 
    $page = intval($_GET['page']);
}

// PAGINAÇÃO INÍCIO ******************************************************/

// Para mostrar a paginação você precisa saber o TOTAL de resultados para sua busca
// Define query e executa, sempre vai obter apenas um resultado
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM tabela ORDER BY campo1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

// descobri o total de páginas usando ceil() que arredonda frações pra cima
// a variavel $max é a mesma definida no exemplo anterior
$totalPages =  ceil($row['total'] / $max);   

// Agora faça o for para imprimir as páginas  
for($i=1 ; $i<=$totalPages; $i++) 
{
    // Imprime separador
    if($i>1)
        echo " | ";

    // Verifica se é a página selecionada usando $page definido no exemplo anterior
    if($i==$page) 
        echo "<b>$page</b>";
    else
        echo "<a href="lista.php?page=$page">$page</a>";
}

// PAGINAÇÃO FIM ********************************************************/

// TABELA DE RESULTADOS INICIO ******************************************/

// Define o limit usado na query
// Exemplo: Pag 1 seria: LIMIT 0, 10 (Começa do resultado 0 e retorna os 10 sequintes)
// Exemplo: Pag 2 seria: LIMIT 10, 10 (Começa do resultado 10 e retorna os 10 sequintes)
$limit = " LIMIT ". ($page-1)*$max .",". $max;

// Define a query e adciona o limit da busca
$query = "SELECT * FROM tb_trabalhador" . $limit;

// Antes você chamava de $sql, mas faz mais sentido chamar de $result
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Seu espaçamento
echo "<br><br>"; 

// [OFF]
// Em outro tópico lhe ensinei uma maneira melhor de fazer isso, pelo visto não usou.
// Parece que o caso é você arrumar um problema pontual e a gente conserta pra você.
// Estamos aqui para ajudar a trazer programadores melhores, então aproveite as dicas
// Não tenha MEDO de tentar, ESTUDE MUITO, corra atrás por você, 
// procure scripts já existentes na internet, edite-os ao seu modo.
// Essas suas dúvidas existem milhares de réplicas no stackoverflow, pt.stackoverflow,
// e em diversos foruns e site. :)

// Mantendo da forma que você fez
while ($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<table>"; 
    echo "<tr><td>Nome:</td>";
    echo "<td>".$exibe["Nome"]."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Morada:</td>"; echo "<td>";
    if ($exibe['Morada']){ echo $exibe['Morada'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Tipo:</td>";echo"<td>";
    if($exibe['Tipo']){ echo $exibe['Tipo'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Email:</td>"; echo "<td>";
    if($exibe['Email']){ echo $exibe['Email'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Alvara Numero:</td>";echo"<td>";
    if($exibe['AlvaraNumero']){ echo $exibe['AlvaraNumero'];}else{echo 'N/D';} 
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
?>

// TABELA DE RESULTADOS FIM *********************************************/
```

Comment: Uma duvida na paginacao.
agora executar a query e mostrar os resultados?

Eu já mostro os resultados no primeiro codigo. esse segundo codigo seria para definir a paginação

Comment: No seu primeiro código você recebe um ID e mostra apenas um item. Como se fosse a pagina ver.php?id=3 (exemplo). A pagina que lista os resultados seria algo como lista.php?page=2 que listaria todos os resultados. Vou editar e exemplificar o 'miolo' que achei que você já soubesse.

Comment: while ($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
echo "<table>"; 
No primeiro codigo tenho a query e a tabela que mostra

Comment: Olhando os outros tópicos feitos por você reparei que sempre tento responder mas nunca são claros suficiente. Tente ser mais objetivo e tente fazer também. Use a documentação do site do php, é muito boa, uma das melhores documentações que já vi.

Comment: Vou editar, aguarde. E lembre-se de nas suas postagens sempre avaliar o melhor comentário, isso colabora bastante para os membros da comunidade StackOverflow PT.

Answer (score 1):

Boas,
Desde de já agradeço a ajuda do @ThiagoBarradas
Vou deixar aqui o codigo completo com a solução.

```
<?php
include("conectar.php");

$quantidade = 1;
$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina'])) ? (int)$_GET['pagina'] : 1;
$inicio = ($quantidade * $pagina)-$quantidade;  
$sql = "Select * From tb_trabalhador order by id asc LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade";
$qr = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
 while($exibe = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
 echo "<table>"; 
 echo  "<tr><td>Nome:</td>";
 echo "<td>".$exibe["Nome"]."</td></tr>";

 echo  "<tr><td>Morada:</td>"; echo "<td>";
 if ($exibe['Morada']){ echo $exibe['Morada'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

 echo "<tr><td>Tipo:</td>";echo"<td>";
 if($exibe['Tipo']){ echo $exibe['Tipo'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

 echo "<tr><td>Email:</td>"; echo "<td>";
 if($exibe['Email']){ echo $exibe['Email'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

 echo "<tr><td>Alvara Numero:</td>";echo"<td>";
  if($exibe['AlvaraNumero']){ echo $exibe['AlvaraNumero'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td>   </tr>";

  echo "<tr><td>Alvara Validade:</td>";echo"<td>";
  if($exibe['AlvaraValidade']){ echo $exibe['AlvaraValidade'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

  echo "<tr><td>Alvara Anexo:</td>";echo"<td>";
  echo '<a href="download_anexo.php?AlvarAnexo=' . $exibe['AlvaraNumero']. '">Abrir anexo</a>';

  echo "<tr><td>Seguro de Acidente Numero:</td>";echo"<td>";
  if($exibe['AcidenteNumero']){ echo $exibe['AcidenteNumero'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

 echo "<tr><td>Seguro de Acidente Validade:</td>";echo"<td>";
 if($exibe['AcidenteValidade']){ echo $exibe['AcidenteValidade'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

 echo "<tr><td>Seguro de Responsabilidade Civil Numero:</td>";echo"<td>";
 if($exibe['SeguroNumero']){ echo $exibe['SeguroNumero'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

 echo "<tr><td>Seguro de Responsabilidade Civil Validade:</td>";echo"<td>";
 if($exibe['SeguroValidade']){ echo $exibe['SeguroValidade'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

 echo "<tr><td>Declaração de Não Divida as Financas Validade:</td>";echo"<td>";
 if($exibe['FinancasValidade']){ echo $exibe['FinancasValidade'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

 echo "<tr><td>Declaração de Não Divida a Segurança Social Validade</td>";echo"<td>";
 if($exibe['SocialValidade']){ echo $exibe['SocialValidade'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

 echo "<tr><td>Declaração de Remuneração de Validade:</td>";echo"<td>";
 if($exibe['RemuneracaoValidade']){ echo $exibe['RemuneracaoValidade'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

 echo "<tr><td>Credencial Entidade Instalador Numero:</td>";echo"<td>";
 if($exibe['InstaladorNumero']){ echo $exibe['InstaladorNumero'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

 echo "<tr><td>Credencial Entidade Instalador Validade:</td>";echo"<td>";
 if($exibe['InstaladorValidade']){ echo $exibe['InstaladorValidade'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

 echo "<tr><td>Credencial Entidade Montadora Numero:</td>";echo"<td>";
 if($exibe['MontadorNumero']){ echo $exibe['MontadorNumero'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

 echo "<tr><td>Credencial Entidade Montadora Validade:</td>";echo"<td>";
 if($exibe['MontadorValidade']){ echo $exibe['MontadorValidade'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

echo "</table>";
 } 

  $sqltotal = "SELECT id FROM tb_trabalhador";
  $qrtotal = mysql_query($sqltotal) or die (mysql_error());
  $numtotal = mysql_num_rows($qrtotal);
  $totalpagina = ceil($numtotal/$quantidade);

  echo '<a href="?pagina=1">Primeira página</a>';

   for($i = 1; $i <= $totalpagina; $i++){
  if($i == $pagina)
   echo $i;
else
  echo "<a href=\"?pagina=$i\">$i</a>"; 
  }

 echo '<a href=\"?pagina=$totalPagina\">Ultima página</a>';
  ?>
```

Comment: Você deve informar este texto: `"Tenho so uma duvida. $sql = "Select * From tb_trabalhador order by id asc LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade"; Nessa linha se eu quiser colocar mais tb cujo o Id seja o mesmo como faço? Obrigado`" como comentário, e não adicionado ao corpo da resposta.

Comment: Tenho so uma duvida.
$sql = "Select * From tb_trabalhador order by id asc LIMIT $inicio, $quantidade";
Nessa linha se eu quiser colocar mais tb cujo o Id seja o mesmo como faço? Obrigado